# WCF Returning model classes

Tags: c#, wcf, model

my problem is the following:

i have implemented a service which generates data (successfully). Now i want to retrieve that data. If i set up the service and the client connection locally on my pc (localhost..), it does work. But when i set up the service onto another machine, it doesn't. My classes look like this.

```
IService
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://bla", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(FaultException))]
    Models.Models GetModels();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
Service : IService
{
    private static Models.Models vm = new Models.Models();
    public Models.Models GetModels()
    {
        return vm;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Models
{
    private static Config.Config _config = new Config.Config();
    public Config.Config Config { get { return _config; } }
}


[DataContract]
public class Config
{
    private static ObservableCollection<General> _general = new ObservableCollection<General>();
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<General> General
    {
        get { return _general; }
        internal set { _general = value; }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class General
{
    private static string _logFile;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string LogFile
    {
        get { return _logFile; }
        set { _logFile = value; }
    }
```

}

The code above returns the model class, but there are no loaded elements in the config class. There should be at least a count of one (General.Count).Do i have to configure my service differently or am i missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error message while consuming the service ?

Comment: unfortunately not. i have checked the part of generating the data (reading xml files and storing them into the objects) and returning the actual model class (GetModels). When i pass the Model.cs, the Config has a count of one stored object, but it seems this information does not get to the client. It returns everytime zero.

Answer (score 0):

Static members of your data classes will not be serialized and sent between client and service. You need to find a solution that works without the static members.

Comment: i see. so i have to return each collection separately or exists a more effective way to do that? the goal is to gain access to all models which holds any data. config is such a class, but there is more.

edit:
i forgot to ask, why then the local setup is working?

Comment: Do you have any reason to have static members? I have a hard time believing, that this works even locally, without any WCF.

Comment: i wanted to access my stored informations of the different classes in one class. it did work with wcf,locally. But i will work now with my collections directly.